# DataTrigger и ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня в модели есть ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _data;
public ObservableCollection<string> Data
{
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Как в разметке XAML для некоторого элемента создать DataTrigger, который бы срабатывал при добавлении/удалении элементов в коллекции? Используя MVVM. Я делаю так, но при добавлении элемента триггер не срабатывает... (Причем если эту коллекцию прибиндить к ListView, то при добавлении/удалении элементов ListView автоматом отображает изменения):

```
<CheckBox Content="Text" IsChecked="{Binding Model.IsSplit}">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.Data, Converter={StaticResource nullOrEmptyToBoolConverter}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

**Добавлено**

Конвертор такой (при добавлении элемента - он просто не вызывается (брейкпоинт в отладчике не реагирует), привязка в коде правильная, так как он же для другого IList в похожем триггере вызывается):

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(IList), typeof(bool))]
public class NullOrEmptyIListToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var m_value = value as IList;
            return m_value.Count == 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите при пустой коллекции менять фон у `checkbox`?

Comment: Если null или 0 элементов, то да, как пример - менять фон чекбокса. Элементы добавляться по кнопке, но триггер не срабатывает...

Comment: `private ObservableCollection<string> _data;` исправьте вот так. возможно просто ошибка привязки

Comment: Это опечатка, исправил, но вопрос остался...

Comment: А почему бы не сделать без конвертора? Например так, ` DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.Data.Count}" Value="0" `

Comment: Так работает! А как с конвертором быть - там можно на null проверить и еще ряд условий...

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете просто прибиндиться к свойству `Count` `ObservableCollection<T>`, т. к. `ObservableCollection<T>` сообщает о его изменениях через интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Если вы хотите проверить на `null`, попробуйте установить у `Binding` `TargetNullValue` или `FallbackValue`.

Ещё один трюк подойдёт, если у вас данные отображаются в каком-нибудь `ItemsControl`'е: вы можете привязаться к свойству `HasItems`. А если `ItemsControl`'а нет, его можно создать:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" Name="IC" Visibility="Hidden" Height="0" Width="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate/> <!-- упростим фреймворку задачу -->
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems, ElementName=IC}"/>
```

(но это, конечно, хак).